# Enter Parameter Value not accepting values

Tags: ssms, ms-access-2010

I'm taking over a database and there is a process to update it, using Access as the front end connected to SSMS.Of course I'm stuck on the first part of 23, Step1A: Appends new records to dbo_tblLR2000NewStandard. It's asking for a couple of parameters, the window has tablename.fieldname and I've tried enter one value from the field but it didn't work. On top of that I'm going to need to update tens of thousands of rows.

Here is the code

```
INSERT INTO dbo_tblLR2000NewStandard ( CaseID, Casetype, [Casetype Txt], [Case Disp Txt] )
SELECT TxtLR2000NewStandard.[Case Id], TxtLR2000NewStandard.Casetype,
       TxtLR2000NewStandard.[Casetype Txt], TxtLR2000NewStandard.[Case Disp Txt]
FROM TxtLR2000NewStandard 
LEFT JOIN dbo_tblLR2000NewStandard
ON TxtLR2000NewStandard.[Case Id] = dbo_tblLR2000NewStandard.CaseID
WHERE (((dbo_tblLR2000NewStandard.CaseID) Is Null));
```

Any suggestions or pointing me towards something I can read would be greatly appreciated. I don't have much IT experience, 2.5 years out of school as a career changer and this is the first database project I've been given 1 year after getting a SQL cert. I'm at a small contractor and there really isn't anyone to ask for help. Am I up the creek?

Comment: Where is this SQL "code"? Are you in an MS-Access query? What is the name of the parameter - and is it one of the field names in your SQL?

Comment: Please format your question so that the error you see is clear and obvious.

Comment: @dbmitch Isn't what I posted referred to as code? Is it just a SQL statement? Sorry for the dumb question. Yes I'm in MS Access, there are queries already built that I'm trying to use. The documentation just says to run them in order, and they are named by what they do, nowhere does it say that I'd be entering parameters. I get two parameter windows, first one asks for TxtLR2000NewStandard.Case Id, the second for  TxtLR2000NewStandard.Case Disp Txt. Both are field names. I've tried entering one Case Id and the Case Disp Txt, and I've tried entering nothing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you're in MS-Access and this SQL is from an 'already-built' query you can open it in Design Mode to see what the issue is. When it comes up with that message it typically means the field doesn't exist in `TxtLR2000NewStandard` - perhaps they use underscores instead of spaces. Without your deign view we can only guess

Comment: @dbmitch I had come across looking at the Design Mode because I got an error message, One or more fields may have been deleted or renamed, The name of one or more fields or tables specified in the join expression may be misspelled, and The join may use an operator that isn't supported in Design view, such as > or <. I found a typo in the column header... Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I can put my suggestion as an answer if you think it helped